# Difference equations applied to DSP

Tags: linear-systems, reference-request

I've found almost nothing about difference equations on the internet. Can you please recommend me something like books or pdf online that handle deep this topic? I'm searching also some exercises. Thank you!

Comment: Also have a look at the following books: **1**-Difference Equations_W.Kelley, **2**-Linear Differential and Difference Equations_R.M.Johnson , **3**-Introduction to Difference Equations_S.Elaydi ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/ and specifically
   https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Difference_Equation_I.html
2. http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm
3. [https://www.amazon.com/Digital-Signal-Processing-Alan-Oppenheim/dp/0132146355](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132146355)
       (need to buy the book)